# How to remove y tick labels in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing histograms for 4 different distributions using subplots. During the final output, I am getting tick labels for the y-axis for the fourth subplot. How shall I ensure it doesn't happen.

```
fig,((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=True,sharey=True)
plt.cla()
nbins = np.arange(-10,10,1)
ax1.hist(x1,bins=nbins)
ax1.set_title('Normal Distribution')
ax1.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax2.hist(x2,bins=nbins)
ax2.set_title('Exponential Distribution')
ax3.hist(x3,bins=nbins)
ax3.set_title('Rayleigh Distribution')
ax3.set_xlabel('Value')
ax3.set_ylabel('Frequency')
ax4.hist(x4,bins=nbins)
ax4.set_title('Random Distribution')
ax4.set_xlabel('Value')
```

Here is the figure I am obtaining after running the code:

[image: subplots]

After adding the following code, it removed y-tick labels for other axes too

```
ax4.set_yticklabels([])
```

Following is the graph -

[image: subplots_1]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange, as I cannot reproduce that behavior. I don't know why ax4 would behave differently from the other axes.

But in any case, since the axes are shared, you cannot just remove the tick labels since that removes them everywhere, as you've discovered. The solution is to make them *invisible* on the desired ax.

```
plt.setp(ax4.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```